# How do I maintain row/column orientation of vectors in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Coming from a background of Matlab/Octave, I have been trying to learn numpy. One thing that has been tripping me up over and over is the distinction between vectors and multi-dimensional arrays. For this question I'll give a specific problem I'm having, but I'd be much obliged if someone could also explain the more general picture behind single-dimensional arrays in numpy, why you would want them in the first place, how to avoid trouble when mixing single and multi-dimensional arrays, etc. Anyway, the question:

I have a 2-D array called X:

```
X = numpy.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
```

and I want to take the last column of X and store it as another 2-D array (ie, a column vector) called Y. The only way I have been able to come with for this is:

```
Y = numpy.atleast_2d(X[:,4]).T
```

but I don't like that for a couple of reasons:

1. I don't feel like I should have to tell it to transpose the vector when the orientation should be implied in X[:,4].
2. Using atleast_2D just seems so cumbersome to use over and over again in code where this situation would come up a lot. It feels like I'm doing something wrong.

So, in short, is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: `np.atleast_2d(x).T` can also be written `x.reshape(-1, 1)`. If you do it a lot, it might be a good idea to define a helper for it, `def ascolumn(x): return x.reshape(-1, 1)`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, the easy way to do what you want:

```
Y = X[:,4:]
```

Now, the reason numpy wasn't doing this when you were trying it before has to do with how arrays work in Python, and actually in most programming languages. When you write something like `a[4]`, that's accessing the fifth element of the array, not giving you a view of some section of the original array. So for instance, if `a` is an array of numbers, then `a[4]` will be just a number. If `a` is a two-dimensional array, i.e. effectively an array of arrays, then `a[4]` would be a one-dimensional array. Basically, the operation of accessing an array element returns something with a dimensionality of one less than the original array.

Now, Python includes this thing called "slice notation," represented using the colon, which is a different way of accessing array elements. Instead of returning an *element* (something with a dimensionality of one less than the original array), it returns a copy of a section of the original array. Essentially, `a:b` represents the list of all the elements at indices `a` (inclusive) to `b` (exclusive). Either `a` or `b` or both can be omitted, in which case the slice goes all the way to the corresponding end of the array.

What this means for your case is that when you write `X[:,4]`, you have one slice notation and one regular index notation. The slice notation represents all indices along the first dimension (just 0 and 1, since the array has two rows), and the 4 represents the fifth element along the second dimension. Each instance of a regular index basically reduces the dimensionality of the returned object by one, so since `X` is a 2D array, and there is one regular index, you get a 1D result. Numpy just displays 1D arrays as row vectors. The trick, if you want to get out something of the same dimensions you started with, is then to use all slice indices, as I did in the example at the top of this post.

If you wanted to extract the fifth column of something that had more than 5 total columns, you could use `X[:,4:5]`. If you wanted a view of rows 3-4 and columns 5-7, you would do `X[3:5,5:8]`. Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: The slightly more precise answer seems to be `Y = X[:,4:5]`, even if X happens to have only 5 columns.

Comment: it returns a view not a copy, "it returns a VIEW of a section of the original array"

Comment: @David Z so to maintain orientation while indexing column `i` you have write `my_array[:, i: i+1]` ???? That's error prone and horrendous no?

Comment: @OldSchool Yes, but if you're trying to maintain orientation, you're probably doing it wrong. A 1D array does not actually have an orientation, and the more natural way to work with it is without having any ideas of orientation in mind. When you try to force foreign concepts like orientation on to an array, in Python/NumPy, then you wind up doing "error prone and horrendous" things like this.

Comment: @David Z: I'm not sure that's right. A principal use of numpy is ostensibly linear algebra. 
I don't think it is unreasonable to require that numpy more easily recognize vector orientation.
ata is entirely different from aat etc...
If it did, perhaps linear algebra could be implemented in the orientation that matches a set of equations, should one wish to do that, without having to write error prone and difficult to read `my_array[:, i: i+1]`

Comment: @OldSchool I would have to disagree, I think it is a little unreasonable to require that NumPy recognize vector orientation. Or more precisely: the NumPy developers made a decision not to imbue 1D arrays with orientation. Requiring that NumPy more easily recognize vector orientation is essentially saying that that decision was _wrong_, and I believe that's unreasonable. Of course it's not the only reasonable decision they could have made, but I believe it's quite a sensible one. Linear algebra is a lot more than just 2D matrix manipulation, after all.

Comment: It is unreasonable to suggest that a decision made by NumPy's developers was wrong? Not sure I can agree with that even if I am not necessarily suggesting that any decision was wrong. I'm also not sure that any decision not to imbue 1D arrays with orientation was successful. The end result is that NumPy 1D arrays do have an orientation, rows, at least under linear algebra operators, and changing that orientation seems to require error prone syntax. I am fairly certain that this could be resolved in a number of ways, improving the current (generally very good) package.

Comment: @OldSchool Yes, I am saying that it's unreasonable of you to say that this particular decision was wrong, when it's merely _different_ from other systems. Though of course you can disagree. Anyway, my main point is that NumPy's 1D arrays do not have orientation, and that it's incorrect to say otherwise. I don't know if this applies here, but over time I've seen quite a few people, usually with a background in Matlab/Octave, who are unable to understand what it means for a 1D array not to have an orientation, and it prevents them from being able to understand or use NumPy arrays effectively.

Answer (score 0):

## Subsetting

The even simpler way is to subset the matrix.

```py
>>> X
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8 9]]

>>> X[:, [4]]
[[4]
 [9]]

>>> X[:, 4]
[4 9]
```

It works somewhat similarly to a Pandas dataframe. If you index the dataframe, it gives you a **Series**. If you subset or slice the dataframe, it gives you a **dataframe**.

### See also

- [This answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861473/16936415)