# Convert row vector to column vector in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

```
import numpy as np

matrix1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
vector1 = matrix1[:,0] # This should have shape (2,1) but actually has (2,)
matrix2 = np.array([[2,3],[5,6]])
np.hstack((vector1, matrix2))

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

The problem is that when I select the first column of matrix1 and put it in vector1, it gets converted to a row vector, so when I try to concatenate with matrix2, I get a dimension error. I could do this.

```
np.hstack((vector1.reshape(matrix2.shape[0],1), matrix2))
```

But this looks too ugly for me to do every time I have to concatenate a matrix and a vector. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 28):

The easier way is

```
vector1 = matrix1[:,0:1]
```

For the reason, let me refer you to [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165416/56541):

> When you write something like `a[4]`, that's accessing the fifth element of the array, not giving you a view of some section of the original array. So for instance, if a is an array of numbers, then `a[4]` will be just a number. If `a` is a two-dimensional array, i.e. effectively an array of arrays, then `a[4]` would be a one-dimensional array. Basically, the operation of accessing an array element returns something with a dimensionality of one less than the original array.

Comment: similarly, slicing returns something with the same dimensionality (or rank in numpy terms) as the original array

Answer (score 16):

Here are three other options:

1. You can tidy up your solution a bit by allowing the row dimension of the vector to be set implicitly:

   ```
   np.hstack((vector1.reshape(-1, 1), matrix2))
   ```
2. You can index with `np.newaxis` (or equivalently, `None`) to insert a new axis of size 1:

   ```
   np.hstack((vector1[:, np.newaxis], matrix2))
   np.hstack((vector1[:, None], matrix2))
   ```
3. You can use `np.matrix`, for which indexing a column with an integer always returns a column vector:

   ```
   matrix1 = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
   vector1 = matrix1[:, 0]
   matrix2 = np.matrix([[2, 3], [5, 6]])
   np.hstack((vector1, matrix2))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

## Subsetting

The even simpler way is to subset the matrix.

```py
>>> matrix1
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]

>>> matrix1[:, [0]] # Subsetting
[[1]
 [4]]

>>> matrix1[:, 0] # Indexing
[1 4]

>>> matrix1[:, 0:1] # Slicing
[[1]
 [4]]
```

I also [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861502/16936415) this in a similar question.

> It works somewhat similarly to a Pandas dataframe. If you index the dataframe, it gives you a **Series**. If you subset or slice the dataframe, it gives you a **dataframe**.

Your approach uses **indexing**, [David Z's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623029/16936415) uses **slicing**, and my approach uses **subsetting**.