# Create vertical NumPy arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using NumPy in Python to work with arrays. This is the way I'm using to create a vertical array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
```

Is there a simple and more direct way to create vertical arrays?

Comment: We need a feature like MATLAB `shift+enter` for editing :D

Comment: Yep! Even I have always thought so!

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy convert row vector to column vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622905/numpy-convert-row-vector-to-column-vector)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `reshape` or [`vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) :

```
>>> a=np.arange(1,4)
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.reshape(3,1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> np.vstack(a)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Also, you can use [*broadcasting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in order to reshape your array:

```
In [32]: a = np.arange(10)
In [33]: a
Out[33]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [34]: a[:,None]
Out[34]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Comment: It would be better if you could add links to your function

Comment: @BhargavRao i was doing that ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) (See Examples [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#newaxis))

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(3)[:, np.newaxis]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

*As a side note*

I just realized that you have used, `from numpy import *`. Do not do so as many functions from the Python generic library overlap with `numpy` (for e.g. `sum`). When you `import *` from `numpy` you lose the functionality of those functions. Hence always use :

```
import numpy as np
```

which is also easy to type.

Answer (score 4):

The best way in my experience is to use `reshape(-1, 1)` because you don't have to specify the size of the array. It works like this:

```
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.reshape(-1, 1)
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplicity and directness is in the eye of the beholder.

```
In [35]: a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
In [36]: a.flags
Out[36]:
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
In [37]: b=np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1)
In [38]: b.flags
Out[38]:
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

The first is shorter and owns its data. So in a sense the extra brackets are a pain, but it's a rather subjective one.

Or if you want something more like MATLAB you could use the `np.matrix` string format:

```
c=np.array(np.matrix('1;2;3'))
c=np.mat('1;2;3').A
```

But I usually don't worry about the OWNDATA flag. One of my favorite sample arrays is:

```
np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
```

Other ways:

```
np.atleast_2d([1,2,3]).T
np.array([1,2,3],ndmin=2).T
a=np.empty((3,1),int);a[:,0]=[1,2,3] # OWNDATA
```