# Numpy print a 1d array as a column

Tags: python, numpy, printing, reshape

I have an array that is 1d, and I would like to print it as a column.

```
r1 = np.array([54,14,-11,2])
print r1
```

gives me this:

```
 [ 54  14 -11   2]
```

and

```
 print r1.shape
```

gives me this:

```
(4L,)
```

Is there something I can plug into np.reshape() so that

```
print r1.shape
```

gives me this?

```
(,4L)
```

And the printed output looks something like

```
 54
 14
-11
 2
```

Comment: `shape` is a tuple.  `(4,)` is standard Python syntax for a 1 element tuple.  `(,4)` is not valid syntax.  Neither is an abbreviation for 2d shapes like (1,4) or (4,1).  (4,1) is the shape of an array with 4 'rows' and 1 'column', which will display as you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work:

```
import numpy as np

r1 = np.array([54,14,-11,2])

r1[:, None]

# array([[ 54],
#        [ 14],
#        [-11],
#        [  2]])
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that unless you [create a vertical version of your array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29658610/2867928). But if you just want to print your items in that format you can use `set_printoptions()` function to set a printing format for your intended types:

```
In [43]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int':lambda x: '{}\n'.format(x)})

In [44]: print(r1)
[54
 14
 -11
 2
]
```

*NOTE*: If you want to apply this function to all types you can use `'all'` keyword that applies the function on all the types.

```
formatter = {'all':lambda x: '{}\n'.format(x)}
```