# Why isn't the shape of the array correct?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I'm having some array operation issues. Here's an example:

```
A = np.ones((5,2))
B = np.ones((5,2)) * 2
X = np.zeros((5,1))

C = A[:,0] + B[:,0]
D = C + X
```

The shapes I'm getting are:

```
shape(A[:,0]) = (5,)
shape(B[:,0]) = (5,)
shape(X) = (5,1)
shape(C) = (5,)
shape(D) = (5,5)
```

When I extract a column from an array, the output is from shape (5,), not (5,1). Is there any way to correct that without having to reshape arrays all the time?

When I add D = C + X, the result is an (5,5) array, but should be (5,1).

Comment: `ones` and `zeros`? are they built in? `shape`?

Comment: @taesu `ones` and `zeros` is from  `numpy` library

Comment: I'm asking op because nowhere does he mention `numpy`, anyways I approved your edit req

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. They're all from numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When broadcasting an array like `C` with `(5,)` with a 2d array, `numpy` adds dimensions at the start as needed, `(1,5)`.  So a `(1,5) + (5,1) => (5,5)`.

To get a `(5,1)` result, you need, in one way or other, make `C` a `(5,1)` array.

```
C[:,None] + X   # None or np.newaxis is an easy way
C.reshape(5,1) + X  # equivalent
```

or index `A` with a list or slice

```
C = A[:,[0]] + B[:,[0]]
```

`A[:,0]` removes a dimension, producing a `(5,)` array.

Note, MATLAB adds the default dimensions to the end; `numpy` because it has a default `C` order, does so at the start.  Adding dimensions like that requires minimal change, just changing the `shape`.

Functions like `np.sum` have a `keepdimensions` parameter to avoid this sort of dimension reduction.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**

```
D = X + C.reshape(shape(X))
shape(D)                        
#(5, 1)
print(D)
#[[ 3.]
# [ 3.]
# [ 3.]
# [ 3.]
# [ 3.]]
```

**Solution 2 (better)** [numpy-convert-row-vector-to-column-vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622905/numpy-convert-row-vector-to-column-vector)

```
C = A[:,0:1] + B[:,0:1]
```

**Why,**

`C` and `X` have different shapes, and you sum row with number, geting a matrix with shape (5,5)

```
print(C)
#[ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]

print(X)
#[[ 0.]
# [ 0.]
# [ 0.]
# [ 0.]
# [ 0.]]
```

Comment: So all the time I get a column from an array, I have to reshape it? Is there any other way? Why is it (5,nothing), instead of (5,1)?

Comment: @Mohamad yes, you can to use `C = A[:,0:1] + B[:,0:1]` instead of `C = A[:,0] + B[:,0]`