# numpy : Want to extract a column, gives a row

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I came from MATLAB to Python and I face some problems dealing with matrices.

So, I have a matrix (implemented as a np.array) and I want to manipulate columns of that matrix.

So, I begin with an initialization :

```
x = np.nan * np.ndarray((2,8))
y = np.nan * np.ndarray((2,8))
```

which give two

```
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Now, I want to put a column vector `v` inside `y` to compute something inside `x` later

```
v = np.array([[v1, v2]]) # if v = np.array([[v1], [v2]], doesn't compute on next line
y[:,0] = np.copy(v)
x[:,0] = y[:,0] + someRandomVector
```

It returns to me an error :

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that `x[:,0]` does not give a column vector as I expected but rather

```
>>> x[:,0]
array([ nan,  nan])
```

Any idea or tips that might help?

Comment: What is `someRandomVector` ? Is it like `v` ?

Comment: SomeRandomVector seems to be (2,2) dimension

Comment: `someRandomVector` is a 2 lines x 1 row vector
I want `v` to behave like a 2lines x 1 row vector, to put it in the first row of `y`

Comment: Paste the result print someRandomVector.shape

Comment: `print someRandomVector.shape` gives `(2, 1)`

Comment: x[:,0:1] 

In this [post][1] is explained why.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165170/how-do-i-maintain-row-column-orientation-of-vectors-in-numpy

Comment: I still doesn't understand why `xapriori[:,0]` gives `array([ nan,  nan])` instead of `array([[nan], [nan]])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>>x[:,0:1] 
print x.[:,0:1].shape
(2,1)
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165170/how-do-i-maintain-row-column-orientation-of-vectors-in-numpy) is explained the motivation and how the array is managed in numpy.

> What this means for your case is that when you write X[:,4], you have one slice notation and one regular index notation. The slice notation represents all indices along the first dimension (just 0 and 1, since the array has two rows), and the 4 represents the fifth element along the second dimension. Each instance of a regular index basically reduces the dimensionality of the returned object by one, so since X is a 2D array, and there is one regular index, you get a 1D result. Numpy just displays 1D arrays as row vectors. The trick, if you want to get out something of the same dimensions you started with, is then to use all slice indices, as I did in the example at the top of this post.
>
> If you wanted to extract the fifth column of something that had more
>   than 5 total columns, you could use X[:,4:5]. If you wanted a view of
>   rows 3-4 and columns 5-7, you would do X[3:5,5:8]. Hopefully you get
>   the idea.

Comment: Instead, I get :
`>>> x[:,0].shape`
`(2,)`

Comment: **Thank You** I kept typing `x[:,0]` when I should have typed `x[:,0:1]`

Comment: So, to get the jth column of `x`, I should type `x[:,j-1:j]` ?
A bit complicated but I should get used to it. **Thank you a lot!**

Comment: Am i correct in saying you could swop x[ :, j - 1 : j ]  for x[ :, [ j ] ]  and get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Subsetting is another approach to consider.

```py
>>> x[:, [0]].shape
(2, 1)
```

You can refer to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861502/16936415) for more information.