# How to keep one-column slice of a matrix as column vector?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

When I extract one column from a matrix, how to keep it as a column vector? From the example below, `a[:,0]` is treated as a row vector.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
a[:,0]
a[:,0] + np.array([[1],[2]]) # I expect a 2x1 vector, not a 2x2 matrix
```

I know that I can convert `a[:,0]` to the desirable dimension with `a[:,0][:, np.newaxis]`. However, I wonder if there is a more general and Pythonic solution about keeping vector as column vector (since in most papers, vectors are columns vectors).

Comment: @all_m As I mentioned, I know how to solve the technical problem of converting into a column vector. I guess I want to know what's a "good practice" in keeping Python vector a column, given that in papers a vector is always a column.

Comment: A 1D numpy `ndarray` is literally just a 1D array - it is not a 'row' or 'column' with a second dimension of length 1. If you *really* want a class that behaves in that way, you can use `np.matrix` (look at the second answer in the question I linked to). However, use of `np.matrix` [is discouraged for a number of reasons](http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935).

Comment: There are more questions about the same issue in addition to the one marked as this one's duplicate, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607419/numpy-want-to-extract-a-column-gives-a-row, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165170/how-do-i-maintain-row-column-orientation-of-vectors-in-numpy

Comment: `a[:,[0]]` preserves the 2nd dimension.  But adding [:,newaxis]` perfectly 'pythonic' or rather, uses a standard feature of `numpy`.  There's nothing wrong with reshaping arrays to suit your needs.  That kind of operation is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, getting a 1d vector from that slice is a feature; it is best to get used to it.

However, if you really do not want that feature, you can work with the matrix object instead.

```
a = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
a[:,0]   #is 2 x 1
```

Comment: Could you explain how is it a feature? (I truly want to think in Python way). I found out that when I use dot product of a 1D array and a 2D array, it doesn't matter whether I transpose it the 1D array or not. I find this lack of explicit dimension very hard to follow.

Comment: @Heisenberg The main reason is for consistency. The concepts of 'row' and 'column' (i.e. `(n, 1)` versus `(1, n)`) only really make sense for arrays that are (at least) two-dimensional. Why should numpy force all arrays to be two-dimensional? Why even stop at two dimensions? `np.ndarray` treats n-dimensional arrays consistently instead of arbitrarily inserting extra axes in order to keep them two-dimensional.

Comment: So when you use dot product, say for the $$x' \Sigma x$$ that appears frequently in statistics, how do you write you clear code for the 1D `x`?

Comment: @Heisenberg In that case you could simply use `x.dot(Sigma).dot(x)`. `a.dot(b)` is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last of `b`.